# How to read wav file data frames in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ipad, wav

I'm working on an iPad (IOS 5) project, and I need to read raw data frames of a WAV PCM file. Ideal solution would be a callback when a frame is read.

I have following questions:

1. Is there a C Library that I can use?
2. Does  a specialized objective C class (like AVAudioPlayer) already exist ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read actual data from .wav file in c or objective-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14342776/how-to-read-actual-data-from-wav-file-in-c-or-objective-c)